# Trouble in calling the bean file in MVN created Spring based Java Project

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven, spring-mvc

I am new user to Spring , I am just learning. I created a mvn Java project using mvn eclipse:eclipse command call and following project structure is getting created.
[image]

Now I Need to create a Spring Bean file like app-context.xml somewhere so that inside a main class I could call-

```
public class SpringLauncher {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] contextPaths = new String[]{"app-context.xml"};
        new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(contextPaths);
    }
```

But whatever I do , the file app-context.xml says not available in the path.
I followed some xample-
http://www.mkyong.com/spring/quick-start-maven-spring-example/

And the tree structure shown here dont have sr/test/java kind of things. Where is the trouble I made ?

[image]

Comment: "Whatever you do"? What *have* you done? Your screenshot doesn't show any `app-context.xml` (which is usually `application-context.xml`, anyhow).

Comment: now  updated the screen shot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your `application-context.xml` and any other files that you want copied to your output directory as-is in `src/main/resources`, under the directory where you want them on the classpath, just as shown in the example (which has the correct directories but doesn't have them added as source directories in Eclipse). For your code, put `app-context.xml` directly in `src/main/resources`.